# Access session from view

Tags: adonis.js

I built login from scratch using adonisjs but I don't know how to check session from view. I need to check when a user is logged-in and the session can be shared everywhere.

I am trying to use global in service provider but it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use authentication with `auth` you can use this tag on view: [Adonis - Authentication](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_loggedin)

```html
@loggedIn
  <h2> Hello {{ auth.user.username }} </h2>
@else
  <p> Please login </p>
@endloggedIn
```

To manipulate the `session` object you can access it in `HTTP Context`: [Adonis - Session](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/sessions)

```js
// Example
Route.get('/login', ({ session }) => {
  return session.get('username') // 'virk'
})
```

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please consult [answer] to read more about how to answer questions